# What is the difference between != NULL and IS NOT NULL in QGIS filter expressions?

Tags: qgis, expression, filter, null

I have a shape layer with an attribute containing `NULL` values to which I would like to apply a filter for values different from `NULL`.

[image]

Using the available GUI for such query construction, one would intuitively try

```sql
"obj_art" != NULL
```

[image]

Which means *'give me all the features with attribute `"obj_art"` different from `NULL`'* (these count definitely more than 0). Testing this query delivers a strange result from my point of view:

[image]

So what I've learned so far is that I can achieve this by using

```sql
"obj_art" IS NOT NULL
```

The question is, what is the difference between `!= NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: _"one would intuitively try"_ Really? Why? NULL is not a value. It is literally the absence of a value. You can't "equal" NULL! The operator `!=` does not mean "is not"; it means "is not equal to". `IS NOT` means "is not" so I think this is perfectly intuitive :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Without the understanding that `NULL` is not a value I would say it *is* intuitive to try to use `=` or `!=` as that is how you assess any other value.  It's not until you know that `NULL` isn't a value that it's really intuitive to use `IS NOT` rather than `!=`.  Many are not aware of what a `NULL` truly is.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Because the syntax for filtering in QGIS works with SQL, I'm assuming here that SQL rules apply. I'm not completely sure if that's entirely correct, but it seems logical and it does explain the behavior.

---

The filter works with SQL, that's why you have to look there for an answer.

In short, when using a logical operator in combination with `null`, the result is always `null`. But in order to test for `null`, SQL comes with  the `IS (NOT)` comparison functionality, which allows to use it for your intended filtering.

Check [@Bohemian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581790/3632673) on StackOverflow for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: Your assumption in the disclaimer is completely correct

Answer (score 24):

`NULL` is *not* a value, therefore it cannot equal `=` or not equal `!=` anything.  It is not the same as zero `0` which *is* a value.

A `NULL` indicates that no value has been recorded in the cell you are looking at.  To check if a value exists you ask if the cell `IS NULL` or if it `IS NOT NULL`

- `IS NULL` checks to see if the cell is empty
- `IS NOT NULL` checks to see if the cell is not empty

If you have some records where a values are `One`, `Two`, `Three` and the rest `NULL` and you want to find everything that isn't `Two` you would need to use something like

```sql
value != 'Two' OR value IS NULL
```

as NULL values do not get returned in an equals/not equals query.  If you used just `value != 'Three'` the result would exclude all `NULL` records as `NULL` isn't a value that can equal or not equal.

Comment: Thanks for this! Stumbled on this after a lot of search on why my A != 'yes' wasn't working. Since all other values were NULL it was returning 0 results - which was not intuitive.