# QGIS 2.18 Training Manual Exercise 1.2.1 - Query Builder Problem

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, query

For Exercise 1.2.1 in the QGIS Training Manual [Training Manual Link](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/preparing_data.html) I attempted to extract data from multipolygon layer using the query;

building != 'NULL'

I had double checked if there were features with no information in their 'building' field in my data and there were many. Unfortunately the query failed with message shown in image below.

[image: Query Failed]

I have tried to exclude spaces, replacing != with NOT, different data, and using " " instead of "NULL"

As I am a bit of a rookie with coding, I have been having no luck.

---

No luck with Kazuhito Answer, "building" != 'NULL'. This query isn't selecting any features, please see photos for reference.

[image: Feature count in layer]
[image: Query result]

Comment: SQL 101: Don't compare against NULL, test for it: `fieldname IS NULL`

Comment: Your syntax seems working perfectly to me. Please see my edit to see if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I've found a post in which this is discussed in gorgeous detail: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-is-not-null-in-qgis-filter-expression

Answer (score 6):

Good catch! I have to wonder why *NULL* is inside double-quotation marks in the linked Training Manual. (Just a typo, maybe. Associated image shows single-quotations.)

Please try with single-quotation marks:

```
"building" != 'NULL'
```

About the error message: because QGIS thinks "xxx" is a field name, it tried to find a fieldname *NULL* and failed.

---

Thanks for your feedback. From your added images I feel your query syntax has been successful.

At the same time, I think I understand what you mean by *This query isn't selecting any features*... and you are right about that point.

Query Builder **filters** the objects according to your query, which means it just hides objects which do not meat your condition. In other words, it **does not select** any object... it simply displays them.

Hope the above clarifies the situation. If you need to **select** them, please try **select (features) by expression** tool through the Field Calculator.