# Summarizing fields with same ID in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, grouping, summarizing

I am looking for a command, that sums the value of the field "Baulast" if they have the same `"ogc_fid"` and if there is a Number in the field `"WEA"`. If there is no number in the field `"WEA"` -> `'keine Baulast'`.
Maybe something like

```
if("WEA">NULL, sum("Baulast","ogc_fid"), 'keine Baulast')
```

So as seen on the Picture, I want to sum the fields that have same `ogc_fid` and have a number in `"WEA"`.

[image]

Comment: What is the type of your `"Baulast"` field? maybe use the `sum(to_int("Baulast"), to_string("ogc_fid"))`. BTW comparison with `NULL` should be done as `if("WEA" IS NOT NULL, sum(to_int("Baulast"), to_string("ogc_fid")), 'keine Baulast')`, check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-is-not-null-in-qgis-filter-expression

Comment: To find features with the same ogc_fid number you may have to write a small python script. Do you need to put that into an new field, back into the Baulast field or make a new feature that combines all 3 of these features?

Comment: I tried Taras answer and it worked.  Just sort the data and select the features (as you have shown) and use the equation. I added a new field called "Result".

Comment: Seems to havent work correctly.. the expression "WEA" IS NOT NULL seems to be not working correct. As shown on picture 2. Even if the Field ogc_fid 222 with WEA is NULL, its summarizing -> Baulast_Ber

Comment: Ah your last edit with the "if("WEA" IS NOT NULL" command at the beginning is doing the job.  Awesome, thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative you may try this expression:

```
if("WEA" IS NOT NULL,
    array_sum(
        array_agg(
            "Baulast",
            group_by:="ogc_fid",
            filter:="WEA" IS NOT NULL
            )
        ),
    'keine Baulast'
    )
```

Comment: Perfect, that's it. Thank you very much.

Comment: bitte, keine Ursache!

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply:

```
sum(
    expression:="Baulast",
    group_by:="ogc_fid",
    filter:="WEA" is not NULL
)
```

See the docs: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#sum

Combine it with if:

```
if(
    "WEA" is not NULL,
    to_string(sum( -- since the field is a string, dont forget to convert the sum result to a string
        expression:="Baulast",
        group_by:="ogc_fid",
        filter:="WEA" is not NULL,
    )),
    'Keine Baulast'
)
```