# Select NULL values by attribute statement

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

Having some difficulty figuring out "and" statements as i am quite new to GIS. What errors am I making in this statement here?

STATUS = 'QC Required' and WORKFROMHOMEEMPLOYEES = 'NULL'

Comment: Since we don't know your data or your intentions, we don't know. What **should** happen?

Comment: id like it to select data from 'qc required' and then from the qc required records to select ones that have null values

Comment: try ... `and WORKFROMHOMEEMPLOYEES is null`

Comment: See [What is the difference between != NULL and IS NOT NULL in QGIS filter expressions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-is-not-null-in-qgis-filter-expression) - the answers there explain the workings of `NULL`

Answer (score 5):

Use `is Null` to select Null values. By using `= 'NULL'` you select a string containing this word. So use:

```
STATUS = 'QC Required' and WORKFROMHOMEEMPLOYEES IS NULL
```

Comment: Sounds like the CA DMV might have this bug in their ticketing system https://radiolab.org/episodes/null